# How to stop for loop when I found the element. In Protractor

Tags: protractor

[image: enter code here]

```
for (var i=1; i<8 ; i++)

 {
  var eleClick = element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Choices for Independence-Guidelines - 3705']"));

  eleClick.isPresent().then(function(result){
    if(result)
    {
      eleClick.click();
      browser.sleep(3000);
      console.log("Able to click");
         }
    else{
      var nextPage = element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Next']"));

      nextPage.click();

      browser.sleep(3000);
      console.log("Unable to click");
    }

  })
```

But when element is found it clicks the element 5 times. I have used break statement but it throws Illegal statement. Can someone please help.

Comment: Please SHOW the code where you use the `break`.  It is hard to  diagnose why it isn't working if we can't see the code you are using !  This site will help you solve your problem but we don't just write the 'right' code for you.

Comment: There are so many issues on so many levels in this piece of code. I don't know where to start from and what to suggest.

Comment: For starters, why do you need a loop here?

Comment: What are you trying to test here?